# how to clean the whole asp.net page in code behind?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have a aspx page with UI and code behind.

I have code in event Page_Load like:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   Me.Response.Write("Clean the page")
   '.....
End Sub
```

but the page still render out with whole thing in aspx(all those markup).

What I want is the only display "Clean the page" in browser for user. 
How to do it?

Comment: The question is not clear, do you want to remove all server-controls from the page programmatically or do you want to prevent that any html is rendered at all? The result is the same but the latter can be achieved in multiple ways.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

Probably you will want to combine it with a:

```
Response.End();
```

Comment: The Response should also be terminated - or else the other page lifecycle events will still trigger (and ultimately render the ASPX). I don't think that anything has actually been written to the Response at `Page_Load` time .. *maybe* headers?

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for hightlighting this I just noticed it and added the additional comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove all the controls like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Clear();
    Response.Write("Clean the page");
}
```

If you have Master Page as well then you can do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Master != null)
        this.Master.Controls.Clear();

    this.Controls.Clear();
    Response.Write("Clean the page");
}
```

or

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = this.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        this.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    Response.Write("Clean the page");
}
```

Comment: Depending on what is meant by "clean" .. outer controls (trivially, from a Master Page) and non-server-run HTML will still bleed.