# Response.Clear not removing anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

If a exception happens, I need to remove the ReportViewer from my page and display a user-friendly + pre-defined message. The problem here is that `Response.Clear` is doing absolutely nothing!

The result (html and scripts output) is exactly the same, with or without `Response.Clear`!

I'm calling it in all places, such as Page_Load and Page_Render (before `base.Render`), etc... at no avail...

How can I "reset" the response and return only my intended message?

Detail: I'm not using MVC!

Comment: Are you using `ajax` to refresh result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider to put the error message to another page and use TransferRequest to execute that page when the exception happens.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've written to the response at all, including headers, clear won't do anything except [erase BUFFERED content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525713(v=vs.90).aspx). It's a stream, and it's started writing to it, so you're stuck after that. Put your exception handling in a better spot - without knowing a lot more about what you're doing, I can't really recommend a specific strategy. We have various levels of error  handling for our apps - some server level (500 errors etc), some page level, some client level (javascript). Depends on what happens and when.

Comment: I don't understand... there's got to be a catch somewhere... the name of the method is pretty clear: 'Response.Clear'! If i call it, I expect the '<body>' to be empty...

Comment: By the time Page_Load hits, some content has been flushed, normally. You would have to remove any controls manually and then clear and be sure to use buffering. See threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154/response-clear-in-asp-net-3-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442057/how-to-clean-the-whole-asp-net-page-in-code-behind

Comment: Also you'd have more to consider, depending on the architecture of the page (master pages etc). the other answer directing you to just transfer out is one way to avoid this type of headache. there's lots of error handling options though.